# How get images from external storage

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin.android, android-sdcard

I have created a folder called `Items` in `/mnt/sdcard/`, from where I want to find `JPG` images. Then I want to display a `ListView` with all the names of the listed images. Upon clicking on one of the names in the list, I would like the image from the path display in an `ImageView`. I have troubles finding the images.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The External Storage path differs from device to device and I strongly suggest you are not using `/mnt/sdcard/` but rater `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory`.

You should be able to use normal C# file operations to get a list of files.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "*.jpg");
```

You can use the filePaths to pass to your custom `Adapter` and inside that load the `Bitmap`s if you want to display them inside of the `ListView`:

```
using(var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filePaths[position]))
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

or you can simply use a `SimpleAdapter` and pass it the `filePaths`, which will then display them as strings.

Then you just need to hook up the `ItemClick` event to get the position in the list clicked and load the correct `Bitmap` into an ImageView.

Also please read http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently if you are using large images, as you have very limited resources.

A good resource for Custom List Adapters: http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview/